# Embedded music player not displaying?

Tags: html, css, embed

I've recently been attempting to insert music into a blog page using the Billy audio player. I've done this before several times, but this time the player isn't showing up on the completed page (I looked on both FireFox and Google Chrome) and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Here's a sample of the code I've written:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Playlists</title>

<style>

/* --- MAIN FORMATTING --- */
body
{
    background: #888888;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 75px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

h1
{
    margin: -26px 0px -4px 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 #000000, 0 1px #000000, 1px 0 #000000, 0 -1px #000000;
}

/* --- CONTENT --- */

.content
{
    width: 620px;
    background-color: #202020;
    border: 1px solid rgba(249,249,249,0.1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

/* --- MUSIC PLAYER --- */
.musicplayer
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    margin: -26px 0px 2px 420px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 12px;
}

/* --- TABLE --- */
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    line-height: 130%;
}

tr
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

td
{
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

</style>

</head>


<body>

<h1>Playlist</h1>

<div class="musicplayer"><embed src="http://www.sheepproductions.com/billy/billy.swf?autoplay=false&f0=http://k007.kiwi6.com/hotlink/2w46d4u3sh/Citizen_Soldiers.mp3&t0=Citizen Soldiers&f1=http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/8kun7qcg5t/Immortals.mp3&t1=Immortals&f2=http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/3rzujskuoo/Rewind.mp3&t2=Rewind&f3=http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/oyl9ee9xsw/No_End_No_Beginning.mp3&t3=No End, No Beginning&f4=http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/xgpyq94ryc/Sound_the_Bugle.mp3&t4=Sound the Bugle&total=5" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="200px" height="10px" name="billy" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/></div>

<div class="content">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width=15px>1.</td>
            <td width=200px>
                "Citizen Soldiers"</a></td>
            <td width=400px>3 Doors Down</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2.</td>
            <td>
                "Immortals"</a></td>
            <td>Fall Out Boy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3.</td>
            <td>
                "Rewind"</a></td>
            <td>Poets of the Fall</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4.</td>
            <td>
                "No End, No Beginning"</a></td>
            <td>Poets of the Fall</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border: 0px;">
            <td>5.</td>
            <td>
                "Sound the Bugle"</a></td>
            <td>Bryan Adams</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what it is I might be forgetting/doing wrong?

EDIT: This is going on a custom Tumblr page, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled your code in notepad++ and it is working in  for chrome and firefox. If you are trying to insert into a blog or forum they might have their own syntax on html posts.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the problem. There was nothing wrong with my code: as it turns out, Tumblr's option to serve blogs over SSL was interfering with the embed. I turned the option off, and the music player now appears as intended.